# wrong commands in ubuntu terminal

Tags: android, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I used a tutorial to allow me to access my Galaxy Nexus on my ubuntu machine using MTP, for some reason it doesn't work manually with android 4.0.

This is the tutorial i used:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-connect-your-android-ice-cream-sandwich-phone-to-ubuntu-for-file-access/

I got the part where you use 'echo' and i typed something wrong, this was the part i did wrong:

```
echo “alias android-connect=\”mtpfs -o allow_other /media/GalaxyNexus\”" >> ~/.bashrc

echo “alias android-disconnect=\”fusermount -u /media/GalaxyNexus\”" >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc
```

I type this word alia instead of alias and now i can't run the script properly meaning i can't compy anything over to my nexus. and when i open a terminal window i get a warning on the top saying:

```
No command 'alia' found, did you mean:
 Command 'ali' from package 'nmh' (universe)
 Command 'ali' from package 'mailutils-mh' (universe)
 Command 'alsa' from package 'alsa-base' (main)
alia: command not found
```

Is there a way i can restart thing, remove the command, im not the greatest when it comes to commandline, im trying but sometimes its hard to find help with what your looking for on the internet without going on sites like this and asking.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually edit your .bashrc file in order to clean the situation.

You can try this opening a shell:

vi .bashrc

or, if you prefer alternate editors:

nano .bashrc

or going on window manager:

gedit .bashrc

Answer (score 1):

Use real quotes : `" is not “`

Comment: Sorry, i pasted that code off the website where the quotes were a little messed up. I did change them when entering them to the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Either run the following:

```
echo "alias android-connect=\"mtpfs -o allow_other /media/GalaxyNexus\"" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "alias android-disconnect=\"fusermount -u /media/GalaxyNexus\"" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Or add the following lines to your ~/.bashrc with the editor of your choice:

```
alias android-connect="mtpfs -o allow_other /media/GalaxyNexus"
alias android-disconnect="fusermount -u /media/GalaxyNexus"
```

And then run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```